# Recyclerview notifyDataSetChanged twice stop pagination

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

i have a fragment that contains a recyclerview which needs pagination 
so once it reach end of it it will call the API to retrieve a new data and append to the list.

in addition i had just added a swipeRefreshLayout to the view once the user swipe for a refresh it will clear the recyclerview and add the data again

Now the problem is that the adapter is unable to detect end of recyclerview once the swipe to refresh is called

### Code Below:

```
 newsSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            generateNews(1);
        }
    });

    adapterNews.setLoadMore(new ToLoadMore() {
        @Override
        public void LoadMore() {
            if (next_offset != 0) {

                newsList.add(null);

                adapterNews.notifyItemInserted(newsList.size() - 1);

                newsApi.GetNews(Constant.ACCESSTOKEN, next_offset).enqueue(new Callback<NewsData>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<NewsData> call, Response<NewsData> response) {
                        Log.d("PAGINATION", "PAGINATION");
                        newsList.remove(newsList.size() - 1);
                        adapterNews.notifyItemRemoved(newsList.size());

                        newsList.addAll(response.body().getNews());
                        next_offset = response.body().getNextOffset();

                        adapterNews.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        adapterNews.setLoaded();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<NewsData> call, Throwable t) {

                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });

    generateNews(1);


    return v;
}
```

the function which generate news is the below

```
private void generateNews(final int offset) {
    newsApi.GetNews(Constant.ACCESSTOKEN, offset).enqueue(new Callback<NewsData>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<NewsData> call, Response<NewsData> response) {
            newsList.clear();
            newsList.addAll(response.body().getNews());
            next_offset = response.body().getNextOffset();

            if (newsSwipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing()) {
                newsSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            }

            news_progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            news_progressText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            newsRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            adapterNews.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<NewsData> call, Throwable t) {

            snackbar = Snackbar.make(getView(), "No Internet Connection", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).setAction("Close", new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    snackbar.dismiss();
                    generateNews(1);
                }
            });
            snackbar.show();

            if (newsSwipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing()) {
                newsSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            }


        }
    });
}
```